# How do I pass a parameter from my new method to my create method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am needing to call a method at the end of my create method if a specific parameter has been passed to the new method. I'm trying to do this without adding a new field to the object I am creating, solely for the purpose of being a temporary "parameter bucket". The parameter won't be used in the creation of the new object, but in the secondary method called after the object is saved.

So in code something like...

```
def new
  @object = Object.new
  if params[:object_id]
    @object_trade = Object.find(params[:object_id])
  end
end

def create
  blah create blah
  if @object.save && @object_trade.present?
    call_method_here(@object_trade.id)
  end
end
```

I can't quite put the pieces together though. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

For what it's worth, i could pass the object or just a parameter for what I am needing to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kirti Thorat rightly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22844903/793309) why an instance variable won't work, but suggests using the session, which is potentially buggy.

What if the user navigates to the 'new' page with an `object_id`, but never submits the form? Instead they hit the back button and make another request to 'new', this time without `object_id`, because they changed their mind. However, `object_trace` is still hanging around in the session and the app wrongly remembers the original `object_id`.

I believe flash would be subject to similar problems.

### Avoiding the session is easy

Render a hidden field in the form that your 'new' action renders:

```
= hidden_field_tag 'object_id', params[:object_id]
```

Then, when you submit the form, the object_id will be passed, and will be available to the create action as `params[:object_id]`.

### Additional reasons to avoid the session

- **Easier to understand and debug**: as your application gets more complicated, you will find it is much simpler if a bug that happens in a request happens *every* time you run the same request with the same parameters. It is no fun trying to fix a bug that you can't reliably reproduce.
- **The stateless approach is just as easy to implement** as the stateful approach
- **Avoid the limitations of whatever type of session storage** your app is configured to use:

  - If using cookie storage, you'll eventually want to store something that's too big to fit in a cookie.
  - If using database storage, you may someday run into issues where values are hanging around in the session indefinitely.
  - If using memcache storage, you will not be able to scale your app to more than one memcached instance, and also your app will break any time you need to restart memcached (or the server it's on).

Comment: These are compelling points. There is certainly less room for error with the stateless model. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine your methods as below:

```
def new
  @object = Object.new
  if params[:object_id]
    session[:object_trade] = params[:object_id]
  end
end

def create
  blah create blah
  if @object.save && session[:object_trade].present?
     @object_trade = Object.find(session[:object_trade])
     call_method_here(@object_trade.id)
     session.delete(:object_trade)  ## Remove object_trade from the session
  end
end
```

Every time you call an action a separate instance of your controller is loaded. Hence, you would not get the `@object_trade` in `create` action. BUT **session** will allow you to share the data between different actions.

### NOTE:

The reason to remove `object_trade` from the session, i.e., `session.delete(:object_trade)` is at a given time only one `new` action can be performed per session.  This way the concern raised by **antinome (in comments)** would not perform activities in `if` block of `create` action. If OP wants to give user a message then he could just add a `flash` message in `else` part stating the reason something like `session key invalid..Please try again` and redirect to new form.

Comment: It would be better to use `flash` instead of `session`. This way it will automatically be cleared after the create action completes.

Comment: I actually tried using flash and was not able to pass the information with it. Perhaps I was simply using it incorrectly.

Comment: @TyrelDenison Glad to help. I also added `session.delete(:object_trade)` which will remove object_trade from the session

Comment: This will break if the user opens the 'new' action in two browser tabs with two different object ids. Also, I've found that debugging is *much* easier when you keep your actions as stateless as possible. (See my answer for a stateless approach.)

Comment: Thats a good point. Please read my Note section in the answer. Plus why would user would want to open 2-3 tabs with different `object_ids` ?

Comment: @Kirti Thorat, with your updated code, doesn't the user still get the wrong object_id when they submit the form in their first tab? I admit it's not super likely that the average user will do that, although I could imagine myself possibly doing that, say if I wanted to create several different items at once in an online auction. But see my answer for a few other reasons. I mainly wanted to point out it's not considered best practice, however, if you are fond of the session and the possible pitfalls don't concern you, I support that.

Comment: @antinome If user submits the first tab then it would not perform activities in `if `block of `create` action at all. If OP wants to give user a message then he could just add a flash message in else part stating the reason something like `session key invalid..Please try again` and redirect to new form.

Comment: @KirtiThorat - I think I didn't explain well - here's what I imagined happening: (1) User navigates to "/objects/new?object_id=1". (2) User changes their mind, navigates to "/objects/new?object_id=2" in a new tab. This sets `session[:object_trade]` to 2. (3) User changes their mind again, closes the second tab, goes back to first tab, clicks "Submit". The create action is run, the object is saved, but `session[:object_trade]` is still 2, whereas the user expected 1, so we pass the wrong id to `call_method_here`.

Comment: This last explanation is the selling point for me on the stateless method. This is a real possibility.